# IRC bot - Give voice to registered nicks

Tags: python, bots, irc

I Recently made a IRC bot, the bot should give voice/+v to registered users. But i can't figure out how?

```
if data.find(' JOIN :' + channel) !=-1:
            selfNick = data.split(":")[1].split("!")[0]
            if selfNick != botnick:
                    rawSend("WHOIS :" + selfNick + "\r\n")
                    reggetNick = "307 " + botnick + " " + selfNick + " :is a registered nick"
                    if data.find(reggetNick) !=-1:
                            # MODE #chan +v selfNick

                    else:
                            print ""
            else:
                    print ""
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't check the `data` at that point, because you know it's the one that contains `" JOIN :"`, rather than `" :is a registered nick"`.

Instead you should wait for another iteration of whatever loop reads your `data`, and see if you get that message in there.

Bear in mind that it won't come directly afterwards, because you might have sent your `WHOIS` while other data was still waiting to be read.

Comment: Or if the network supports extended-join: http://ircv3.net/specs/extensions/extended-join-3.1.html